# Oauth2 problem when downloading a video from the HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, video, oauth-2.0

I have a HTML5 video tag with the src served by a service with oauth2 authentication.
I'm using ServiceWorker to inject the bearer token into the GET request and it works, I can see the video.
The problem is when I try to download the video (using both the download command from the tag or right+click > Download video as...) where the response is 401, because this request is not intercepted by serviceWorker.

How can I fix this problem?